# RabbitMQ Performance Tool

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to use this tool (displaying the results in HTML)

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test/blob/master/html/README.md

trying to generate messages into ***topic exchange named: "MYXG.XYZ"***

but i just get it into default direct exchange

my json is

cat spec-file.js

```
 [{'name': 'AMQPe',
   'type' :'simple',
   'uri': 'amqp://guest:guest@192.168.127.23:5672',
   'exchange-type': 'topic',
   'exchange-name': 'MYXG.XYZ',
   'routing-key':'#',
   'variables': [{'name': 'min-msg-size', 'values': [3200]}],
   'producer-rate-limit': 30000,
   'params': [{
       'time-limit': 100,
       'producer-count': 4,
       'consumer-count': 2
   }]
}]
```

can you help?